# How to check if Entity item was added in Async C# MVC Core method

Tags: asynchronous, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-identity, entity-framework-core

I am writing my own implementation of IUserStore and IUserPasswordStore and I need to prepare async method `CreateAsync` which will return `IdentityResult`. So far I have this:

```
    public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(User user)
    {
        Users.Add(user);
        //await Users.AddAsync(user);
        SaveChanges();
        //await SaveChangesAsync(user);
        //alternative version is commented

        if (<What to put there>)
        {
            return IdentityResult.Success;
        }
        return IdentityResult.Failed(new IdentityError { Description = $"Could not insert user {user.Email}." });
    }
```

I am really not sure what should I put inside `if`. I can only use async methods, so there is no really any result when I run this function. Any tips? I'd really appreciate.

Usually I'd just use `Any()` but this implementation doesn't allow me. If you need more code, just ask in comment, I'll provide, however I think this is enough info for question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SaveChanges()` and `await SaveChangesAsync();` return an int that is the number of affected records if the save operation has done successfully. You can check the returned value and return the relevant result.

```
var success = await context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;

return success
    ? IdentityResult.Success
    : IdentityResult.Failed;
```